# convert current and actual time to GMT in ionic datetime select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have ion-datetime from ionic : I need when the user select the time to convert it to gmt it means if the user select 12:00 pm the time will receive on the server 9:00am

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"
                formControlName="TripDateTime">

  </ion-datetime>
```